# Multiple specified separator in split() Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to specify multiple separators in split() in python?

```
input = "print{hello world};x = 2 + 3;"
x = input.split('{') #this works but not the desired OP
x = input.split('{','}') #error 
x = input.split('{}') #this works but not the desired OP
```

Desired OP:

```
['print', 'hello world', ';x = 2 + 3;']
```

Comment: For that case you could use re.split

Comment: `input.replace('}', '{').split('{')`

Comment: You can you please add expected output to the question. You can [edit] your question here.

Comment: I think RE is made for this purpose not split at simontanously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) in this way:

```
import re

my_input = "print{hello world};x = 2 + 3;"
re.split('{|}', my_input)
```

output:

```
['print', 'hello world', ';x = 2 + 3;']
```